# If every vertex of a planar graph has an even degree, it’s 2-colourable

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Can somebody, please, explain how to prove this theorem:

**If every vertex of a planar graph has an even degree, it’s 2-colourable.**

I understand that we can make a dual graph out of original. The number of vertices will be the same as number of faces in the original graph. The number of edges will be the same as in the original graph. But what should I do next to prove the theorem?

Comment: I think you'd probably find it easier (more structured?) to prove that all of the following are equivalent for a planar graph $G$: $G$ is $2$-colorable $\iff G$ is bipartite $\iff$ every face of $G$ is of even length $\iff$ the dual of $G$ is Eulerian (i.e. has vertices all of even degree). The first and last equivalences in particular are immediate, with the middle one being simple as well using some parity considerations. Let me know if you're still stuck while trying to use this proof outline.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time You should transform your excellent comment into an answer (hopefully beginning by "A big hint : ")

Comment: $K_3$ is a planar graph, and every vertex has degree $2$, but I can't find a $2$-colouring.